# Google Cloud Platform free trial question

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a question about Google Cloud Platform!

I set up my billing account and am on the free trial, which has a $ 300 credit to use for 12 months. The only service I will use is Firebase (only Realtime Database and Storage).

Reading the Google Cloud Platform documentation, in the free trial rules it says the following:

"**You can't have more than 8 colors (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time**".

I couldn't understand this sentence, does that mean that, for example, if I launch an application using the firebase database, I can't have more than a few people using the app at the same time?

Note: my project on firebase is on the blaze plan, but I'm participating in the free trial. I now intend to launch a social networking app where many users will be in the app at the same time. If you can help me get this question out, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see at the documentation program [12-month, $300 free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) has some limitations:

> Your free trial credit applies to all Google Cloud resources, with the
>   following exceptions:
>
> - You can't have more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time.
> - You can't add GPUs to your VM instances.
> - You can't request a quota increase. For an overview of Compute Engine quotas, see Resource quotas.
> - You can't create VM instances that are based on Windows Server images.
>
> You must upgrade your account to perform any of the actions in the
>   preceding list.

Sentence "You can't have more than 8 cores (or virtual CPUs) running at the same time." related to activities that result to spinning VM instances that you can see at `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances`. For example, you can create VM instance (or a few VM instances) and they could use up to 8 vCPUs in total. This limit has no connection to Firebase.

Accordingly to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/use-cases):

> Firebase Hosting is a fully-managed hosting service for static and
>   dynamic content as well as microservices. The service is backed by SSD
>   storage and a global CDN (content delivery network).
>   Zero-configuration SSL is built into Firebase Hosting, so content is
>   always delivered securely.

and to find more information you should look at the Firebase documentation like [Usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) and [Free quota](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#free-quota):

> Cloud Firestore offers free quota that allows you to get started at no
>   cost. The free quota amounts are listed below. If you need more quota,
>   you must enable billing for your Cloud Platform project.

[image: Firebase_Free_quota]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Serhii! I know the free limits of firebase. So, if I'm going to use only the Realtime Database and Storage from Firebase, probably the costs of the month will all be discounted from the $ 300 credits available, correct?

Comment: I doubt about it. I'd recommend to to reach [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) with this question, it's always free for billing related questions, or [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/billing).